# Create view on h2 database

Tags: sql, h2

I'm trying to create a view on H2SQL, but i cannot find the correct syntax.

I'm using:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Log
AS
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable
```

And i receive the error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE VIEW DBO.LOG "; expected "COMMENT, (, AS";
```

What is the right syntax?

Comment: try to add semicolon at last after dbo.MyTable;

Comment: can you add full view code also, because your error message says different what you have in view

Comment: THe code is exactly this one. I have a bigger select, but i reduced it to this simple line and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Based on the error it seems like it's trying to parse `CREATE VIEW dbo.Log ` as an independent statement. Not sure what would cause this. Seeing the actual code might help.

Comment: When i reduce the code in one line it works fine! Is it a bug?

Comment: Try putting that in one line as `CREATE VIEW Log AS SELECT * FROM MyTable` without the schema?

Comment: @Renalf Might be a bug. Are you using the H2 Console to execute the queries? I've never used it myself but from the screenshots I see on their website all of the statements seem to be on one line. I would suggest using something like DBVisualizer instead if that is the case.

Comment: It's definetely a bug. In the console it works fine, but im running it in a RUNSCRIPT at the connection, and it doesn't support multiline view... it has to be all in one line! =/

Comment: Similar issue has been resolved in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953037/spring-mvc-hibernate-encoding-multi-line-import-sql

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a bug on this version of h2 (1.4.182).

When running a CREATE VIEW from a RUNSCRIPT command, it doesn't handle well the line-breaks (\n) on the file. I resolved adding a comment (--) before each line break.

Comment: Adding a comment `--` didn't solve the problem for me. So I had to re-format a statement into one line and it worked. Thank you for the tip! Can you also include into your answer a link to this bug in H2 issue tracker? I can't find it anywhere.