# Spring Mvc Hibernate Encoding/Multi-line import sql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring MVC,

On project startup i have set `database` to import default `sql`
with hibernate configuration `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files`.
Data inside `import.sql` is encoded with `UTF-8`.

> Console Output

```
 ERROR: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000388:
 Unsuccessful: INSERT INTO menu (id, DATE_CREATED, DATE_DELETED,
 DATE_UPDATED, TITLE_ENG, TITLE_GEO, TITLE_RUS, ENABLED, PARENT_ID,
 URL, SITE_ID, USER_ID) VALUES 

 ERROR:
 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - You have an error in your
 SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
 version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

 ERROR:
 org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: (1,
 '2015-09-10 12:00:00', NULL, NULL, 'About Us', N'áƒ©áƒ•áƒ”áƒœáƒ¡
 áƒ¨áƒ”áƒ¡áƒ�áƒ®áƒ”áƒ‘', 'About Us', b'1', NULL, '/article/view/1', 3,
 1).
```

Comment: I am not familiar with import_files, but from the output my guess is that sql statements in the file span two lines but import_files expect each sql statement to span only one line causing "insert ... values" and "the value list" to be treated as two separate statements. Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673802/how-to-import-initial-data-to-database-with-hibernate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Make sure you are setting the JDBC driver to use UTF-8:

   `jdbc:mysql://dbname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8`
2. In `persistence.xml`, set the hibernate connection charset:

   `<property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>`

If your `resources/import.sql` file is multi-line, add:

```
<property 
  name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor"
  value="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor" 
/>
```

or for Spring Boot, in `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.charSet=UTF-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
```

Comment: Best answer find out that the problem was really with multiple lines and with encoding also, nice work dude!

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot, if you use Hibernate 6, extractor changed its name and place. New way is:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.script.MultiLineSqlScriptExtractor
```