# HSQL - insert into table with multiple values

Tags: hsqldb

There is a large HSQL-import-data.sql scripts. I lists all inserts which are required to fill the database with

```
INSERT INTO table (name, firstname) VALUES ('john', 'john);
INSERT INTO table (name, firstname) VALUES ('mark', 'mark);
```

I would prefer to rewrite it like for better readability

```
INSERT INTO table (name, firstname) VALUES 
                  ('john', 'john'),
                  ('mark', 'mark);
```

Unfortunaletly I do not know to achieve it with hsql. If I put the values all in one line it works, but then the script becomes not more readable. So how i mark that a statement continues on the next line. Just as an example in the bash world this would be the `\`character.

Comment: Are you using SqlTool.jar to import the script?

Comment: No - I am using it in a spring boot profile to have some local test-data.

Comment: Thank you @fredt . your question helped me to find out that this is a hibernate issue not hsqldb issue. I found the solution that I have to reconfigure hibernate a bit with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953037/spring-mvc-hibernate-encoding-multi-line-import-sql