# How to modify DB schema after generation but before test execution?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, integration-testing

#### Long story short

I want to generate DB schema from Hibernate mappings and then replace a specific table with a view of the same name before the application starts.
How can I do this using Spring / Hibernate / DbUnit / JDBC or something else?

#### My problem in details

I have a few integration tests that are executed against an in-memory database.
There's an `AView` view in a real database and it's mapped in Java code as

```java
@Entity @Table @Immutable
public class AView {}
```

I'm generating H2 DB schema from Hibernate mappings for integration tests. And during test application context initialization this **view is created as a table.** From logs:

```
Hibernate: drop table AView if exists
Hibernate: create table AView (...)
```

Some tests fail because of this.

#### The idea

In order to fix this, I want to make H2 DB schema as similar as possible to the real DB schema. First, I want to generate DB schema from Hibernate mappings, and then replace `AView` table with `AView` view.

#### What I have tried

I have found a similar question: [How to execute sql script after db schema generation but before application startup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44289433/1429387)

I created a file schema.sql with `DROP TABLE / CREATE VIEW` statements. I tried to put the file in src/test/resources/schema.sql but it's not picked up automatically by Spring. I tried to specify this file explicitly in `@Sql` annotation, but it still doesn't have a visible effect.

I execute the tests via IntelliJ IDEA (if this is important).

#### My Code

Test and Test application context:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestH2Config.class })
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class AViewServiceIT {}

@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:datasource-h2.properties"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
//@Sql({"/schema.sql"})
public class TestH2Config {}
```

datasource-h2.properties

```
datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:itest;MODE=MSSQLServer;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS itest\\;SET SCHEMA itest 
datasource.username=sa
datasource.password=

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

Spring framework version is 4.1.9.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `import.sql` file in the root of your classpath as a means to have Hibernate execute a set of SQL commands after the schema has been built.  Given that you wish to do this specifically for tests only, placing it in the test root classpath should be sufficient.

Comment: It works! Though I had to re-format my `CREATE VIEW` statement because of the H2 bug mentioned here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/27317144/1429387